# WSO2 Carbon Crypto Service Missing property

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0 is starting, I get the following info in the console output:

```
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.internal.DefaultCryptoProviderComponent} -  'CryptoService.Secret' property has not been set. 'org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.SymmetricKeyInternalCryptoProvider' won't be registered as an internal crypto provider. Please set the secret if the provider needs to be registered.
```

This is the configuration I used in the /repository/conf/carbon.xml :

```html
<!--
       Configurations related to Carbon Crypto Service which is a crypto framework used inside Carbon products.
    -->
    <CryptoService>

        <Enabled>true</Enabled>

        <!-- The crypto provider which is used for internal data encryption and decryption -->
        <InternalCryptoProviderClassName>org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.KeyStoreBasedInternalCryptoProvider</InternalCryptoProviderClassName>

        <!--
            The crypto provider which is used for the crypto needs which come when communicating with external parties.
            e.g. Signing, Decrypting.
        -->
        <ExternalCryptoProviderClassName>org.wso2.carbon.core.encryption.KeyStoreBasedExternalCryptoProvider</ExternalCryptoProviderClassName>

        <!--
            The list of key resolvers which will be used based on the context when handling crypto with external parties.

            e.g. Resolving the public key of an external entity.
        -->
        <KeyResolvers>
            <KeyResolver className="org.wso2.carbon.crypto.defaultProvider.resolver.ContextIndependentKeyResolver" priority="-1"/>
        </KeyResolvers>

    </CryptoService>

<!--
            The KeyStore which is used for encrypting/decrypting internal data.
            This block is read by Carbon Crypto Service.
        -->
        <InternalKeyStore>
            <!-- Keystore file location-->
            <Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/internal.jks</Location>
            <!-- Keystore type (JKS/PKCS12 etc.)-->
            <Type>JKS</Type>
            <!-- Keystore password-->
            <!-- <Password svns:secretAlias="Carbon.Security.KeyStore.Password">password</Password> -->
            <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
            <Secret>wso2carbon</Secret>
            <!-- Private Key alias-->
            <KeyAlias>wso2carbon</KeyAlias>
            <!-- Private Key password-->
            <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>
        </InternalKeyStore>
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0+ or EI6.6.0+ where deployment.toml file is used:

```
[encryption]
key = "CryptoService.Secret"
```

This will add proper config to carbon.xml on start.

For more info about how new configuration works: [deployment.toml configuration options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59773570/deployment-toml-configuration-options)

For older version applies configuration in carbon.xml .. add tag Secret to CryptoService tag:

```
<CryptoService>
..
<Secret>SECRET_KEY</Secret>
</CryptoService>
```

Comment: I face this issue an `wso2is-5.11.0`, Can you help me how can i resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an element  with a value. This value will be used as the SymmetricKey

```
<CryptoService>
...
<Secret>SECRET_KEY</Secret>
</CryptoService>
```