# deployment.toml configuration options

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

new feature of "WSO IS 5.9.0" is the deployment.toml , but i have not found the configuration options nor the way how one can set the xml config file from this file.

For example, if I want to enable in carbon.xml option EnableHTTPAdminConsole, what should one do?

```
[server]
hostname = "my.server.com"
node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
base_path = "https://$ref{server.hostname}:${carbon.management.port}"
enable_h_t_t_p_admin_console = true
enable_http_admin_console = true
EnableHTTPAdminConsole = true
```

does not work

Also, i have tried to modify in my docker image:

```
wso2is-5.9.0/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/carbon.xml.j2
```

or

```
wso2is-5.9.0/conf/carbon.xml
```

But all these files gets overwritten.

My UseCase is to use WSO2IS in K8S without the port.

https://wso2is.my.domain/ > k8s nginx ingress : 443 (manages certificate) > wso2is-service > wso2is-pod : 9763 (plain http)

However the question still resides, what configuration options are available in deployment.toml

Comment: This property is not templated. Hence as a workaround un-comment the property  *<EnableHTTPAdminConsole>true</EnableHTTPAdminConsole>* in IS5.9.0/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/carbon.xml.j2 file and restart the server.

Comment: This was intentionally left out, as we no longer recommend HTTP based admin console. Is there any particular reason you require this?

Comment: @pulasthi7 Yes, my intetion was to deploy application within k8s cloud where ssl would be managed by the nginx proxy. I was not able to manage connection from 443 > nginx > service > pod because ssl conneciton over ssl connection was not working.. the option was to use ssl to forward to unsecure server, within secure cloud, but the WSOIS redirects always to secure port, and nothing on ouside of the cloud listens to that port..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like not possible through the deployment.toml. As a workaround, you can uncomment the property in

> wso2is-5.9.0/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/carbon.xml.j2

Report this as an issue: https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues

Comment: Hi, this does not seems to work for me. the carbon.xml.j2 gets overwritten when the pod starts as well as conf/carbon.xml

Answer (score 2):

If the above fix is not getting applied, properly your docker image is getting overridden with the default configs. Can you try to build a new docker image with requested changes? This link https://github.com/wso2/docker-is/tree/5.9.0/dockerfiles/ubuntu/is can help you to build the image.

But I am not sure why you cannot access ssl(9443) from Nginx ingress. Maybe you can try this sample Nginx ingress https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-is/blob/master/advanced/is-pattern-1/templates/identity-server-ingress.yaml

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, i have posted the answer as post

Answer (score 2):

The answer to question what can be configured using deployment.toml has answered Buddhima, so i will mark his answer as answer.

One can look trhough the templates f.e.

```
wso2is-5.9.0/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/carbon.xml.j2
```

And can see all the options.

Answer to EnableHTTPAdminConsole answered pulasthi7 that it was intented left out.

I found workaround for the ingress to connect to ssl

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
  name: wso2is-ingress
  namespace: wso2is
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - wso2is.k8s.mydomain.com
    secretName: tls-wso2is
  rules:
  - host: wso2is.k8s.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: wso2is-is-service
          servicePort: 9443
        path: /(.*)
```

The most important line:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
```

This way the connection to is encrypted to ingress nginx using its own certificate, and from nginx to the pod using certificate in the pod.